# jQuery UI - dropped element -> from which div was it dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery UI and get some information of a dropped item.
I have three areas on the screen:

```
<div id="area1"></div>
<div id="area2"></div>
<div id="area3"></div>
```

In these areas, I put elements which are draggable with jQuery UI.

Now if an element is dropped from one to another area, I will not only get the area number in which the element is dropped to, I also want the area number where the element was dropped before the new drop.

I created a full working example: http://jsbin.com/iyaya3/
There is a blue draggable element and if I drag it from area1 to area2, I want to have the alert message with "dragged from area1 - dropped to area2".

How can this be done?

Best Regards, Tim-.

Comment: May i know how to get the parent of the droppable area ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, I updated your `jsbin` - http://jsbin.com/iyaya3/3

It works like this:

1. Take initial parent element's id and save it on draggable using `jQuery.data`
2. When dropping it on droppable, update data

Answer (score 1):

I've got two ideas:
1) You can put a class or ID on the elements in each div:

```
<div id="area1"><node class="from1"></node></div>
<div id="area2"><node class="from2"></node></div>
<div id="area2"><node class="from2"></node></div>
```

And then test for that when you have the item

2) Write a function to do the clone instead of relying on the drag and drop to do it for you (http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper) and then test for the parent and store that (in a singleton outside the scope of the dragger) where you can get it later.

I think I would prefer the first (even if you don't have html access to add these classes, just add it with javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In your `draggable` setup, add this:

```
start: function(event,ui){
  ui.helper.data('from-id',  $(this).parent().attr('id') );
}
```

This will attach, as data, the ID of the container from which the element is being dragged.

Then, in the `droppable`, you can have:

```
 alert( 'I was dragged from ' + ui.draggable.data('from-id') );
```

Here's the [updated jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iyaya3/4).

---

Edit: The `start` function creates a closure, so `$(this).parent().attr('id')` continues to point to the original parent. One solution to this problem (if you wish to keep a start function) is to clear `start` when the drag stops:

```
stop: function(event,ui){
  ui.helper.draggable({ start: null }); 
}
```

This will allow the `data` methods in the droppable handlers to update the `from-id` without being immediately reverted to the original value by the `start` function.

Here's a [revised jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iyaya3/5) example.

Comment: This doesn't work, apparently element's parent does not change when dropped.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the draggable `start` function creates a closure, capturing the state of the original container despite the reparenting. One way around this is to remove the `start` behavior after that initial drag (I'm updating the above accordingly). Another way is to avoid using `start` at all, as in German Rumm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$(element.draggable).parent().attr('id'))` works for me

Answer (score 0):

I removed the duplicated code and solved the problem by saving the previous element id by the data() function.

JS Bin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#area1').append('<div class="shoulddraggable" style="width:100px;height:100px;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:blue;" data-elementid="100"></div>');
  $(".shoulddraggable").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    revert: "invalid",
    scope: "items",
  });

  $(".shoulddraggable").data('previousId', 'area1');

  $('.droppable').droppable({
      scope: "items",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert('Previous container id: ' + ui.draggable.data('previousId'));
        alert("Element: "+ui.draggable.data("elementid")+" dragged into" + $(this).attr('id'));
        ui.draggable.data('previousId', $(this).attr('id'));
      }
  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I will have more elements than one. So this solution won't work. What's possible is to write a attribute to the draggable element, read and update it. But hopefully there is a better solution?

Comment: will not work for multiple draggables - latest one will overwrite `previousDivId` for all. Put $(this).attr('id') value into `data()` on draggable: `ui.draggable.data('previousId', $(this).attr('id'))`